# How to convert python time to java date

Tags: java, python, time

I have a python date formatted like this `1418572798.498` within a string.
In Java the dates are formatted like this `1418572798498`.

How to convert this string to Java date?
Is there any third party library to use for the conversion?

Comment: That's not "python time", btw. That's Unix/POSIX time (seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00). "Java time" is the same but in microseconds :-P

Comment: You just turn the string into a float, and then multiply that number by 1000

Comment: @RicardoCárdenes No, not microseconds. The java.util.Date class uses milliseconds since epoch, as does the Joda-Time library. The new java.time package in Java 8 (JSR 310) uses nanoseconds since epoch. Some databases such as Postgres use microseconds since epoch. See [this diagram](http://i.stack.imgur.com/cpOL8.png).

Comment: Sorry, miliseconds. That was a brainfart.

Comment: @davidzhao Please search StackOveflow before posting. This question has been addressed *many* times.

Comment: @BasilBourque, i konw that question, but they are different. i just want to konw is there any better ways. thans for your wanning.

Comment: @davidzhao You should explain in your Question how it is different from near duplicates. I don't see a difference yet. Same answer for your Question and the many duplicates: Convert string to a number, multiply by a thousand to get a long/Long, feed to constructor of java.util.Date (or better, Joda-Time).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like:

```
String number = "1418572798.498";
long d = Long.parseLong(number.replace(".", ""));
System.out.println(d + " " + new Date(d));
Output:
1418572798498 Sun Dec 14 21:29:58 IST 2014
```

Comment: it's work but not rubust, thans

Comment: What do you mean by not robust? I will try to modify..

Comment: thanks, i think i need change the incomes.

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
float time = Float.parseFloat(string);
long actual_time = (int)(time*1000);
Date d = new Date(actual_time);
```

Comment: Integer.parseInt will throw a NumberFormatException for the string given by the OP. I think a float or double should be used...

Comment: @davidzhao Now it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the decimal point and convert it to a float.